Perform aggregations on a Pandas Dataframe with a multi-index
I am trying to perform a number of operations on a Pandas Dataframe.
The dataframe is obtained by loading data from an SQL query.
select
    price,
    date,
    type
from
    schema.my_table
order by
    date desc;

Here's an example of what this input looks like:
    price   date        key
0   91000   1995-01-03  D
1   44000   1995-01-03  T
2   125000  1995-01-06  T
3   45950   1995-01-11  S
4   30000   1995-01-11  T
5   92000   1995-01-12  D
6   127000  1995-01-17  D
7   95000   1995-01-20  D
8   35000   1995-01-20  T
9   175000  1995-01-20  D
10  80500   1995-01-23  S
11  80000   1995-01-24  D
12  44950   1995-01-25  S
13  96000   1995-01-26  S
14  135000  1995-01-26  D
15  230000  1995-01-26  S
16  41500   1995-01-27  T
17  68995   1995-01-27  D
18  133000  1995-01-27  D
19  80000   1995-01-27  S
20  52500   1995-01-27  T
21  59450   1995-01-30  D
22  60000   1995-01-31  D
23  44000   1995-01-31  T
24  47000   1995-01-31  T
25  55000   1995-02-01  T
26  35000   1995-02-02  F
27  50000   1995-02-02  T
28  91000   1995-02-06  D
29  107000  1995-02-06  D
30  39950   1995-02-10  T

My objective is to produce a dataframe which has:

A multi-index of ['key', 'date']
Columns price_mean and price_std (standard deviation)
The mean and standard deviation should be calculated on a rolling window basis, where the width of the window is 30 days, and the window advances in steps of 1 day

I can just about do one of these operations myself, but I do not know how to compose them all together.
In particular, I got hung up on trying to use rolling to create a windowed function for creating aggregations mean and std.
By default this appears to use 30 samples, not 30 days of data.

Do you want a groupby.rolling? df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) ; out = df.groupby('key').rolling('30D', on='date')['price'].agg(['mean', 'std']).add_prefix('price_')
